# From where is taken Alpha 3 language extension in windows/delphi?

Tags: windows, delphi, localization, locale, globalization

Under delphi, when I click Project > Language > add I can see a list of language with an **alpha 3 extension code** (example: `afk` for Afrikaans, `aze` for Azeri, `fra` for french, etc.) Those alpha 3 code **are not ISO 639-3** alpha 3 code! so where are those alpha 3 code are coming from? those code seam to be related to windows and not to Delphi, but I can find from where exactly.

Note: under Windows 10, the Project > Language > add show many languages with ZZZ as extension, like ZZZ for Dzongkha, what it's mean?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, that string is taken from a call to [GetLocaleInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnls/nf-winnls-getlocaleinfoa) with `LCType` set to `LOCALE_SABBREVLANGNAME`.

See: [LOCALE_SABBREV* Constants](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/win32/intl/locale-sabbrev-constants)

Comment: thanks ! in this way something wrong with the windows api because for GetLocaleInfo($0C51, LOCALE_SABBREVLANGNAME, Language, LOCALE_NAME_MAX_LENGTH); it's return ZZZ :( seam that LOCALE_SABBREVLANGNAME is not supported anymore